# In Terraform, how do I define a ValidateFunc on an attribute that uses *schema.ResourceData (to validate one attribute based on values of others)?

Tags: go, terraform, terraform0.12+

I am building a Terraform Project that uses the old Terraform Plugin SDK v2 (not the new Plugin Framework). Recently, I've defined a validation function on an attribute in a resource:

```
"custom_attribute": {
    Type:         schema.TypeString,
    Required:     true,
    Description:  "Some Description",
    ValidateFunc: validateCustomAttributeValue,
},
```

```
func validateCustomAttributeValue(val interface{}, key string) (warns []string, errs []error) {
    customAttributeValue := val.(string)

    // listValidCustomAttributeValues() returns a list of valid values of "custom_attribute"
    listOfValidCustomAttributeValues := listValidCustomAttributeValues()

    isValidCustomAttributeValue := slices.Contains(listOfValidCustomAttributeValues, customAttributeValue)
    if !isValidCustomAttributeValue {
        errs = append(errs, fmt.Errorf("some custom error"))
    }

    if customAttributeValue == "SPECIFIC_VALUE" {
        warns = append(warns, `some custom warning`)
    }
    return warns, errs
}
```

I would like to write a similar function for a different attribute (say `X`), but in the `ValidateFunc` of `X`, I would like the ability to check the values of other attributes in the resource and based on those values, return errors/warnings (basically, validate the value of `X` based on values of other attributes in the resource).

To do this, the signature of the `ValidateFunc` I've used in the example above does not allow me to use `d *schema.ResourceData` as an argument, and any workaround I try in this regard does not work; but I am badly in need of using `d *schema.ResourceData` somewhere in the `ValidateFunc`.

May I get some ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: Can you use `func (_ *resourceName) ValidateConfig(context.Context, resource.ValidateConfigRequest, *resource.ValidateConfigResponse)` instead? It would be for validation on the entire resource config, but it would work for you.

Comment: Thanks for that idea - however, I'm new to Terraform and am unable to find good resources on this, also that it appears this function would be common to the entire provider and not just to the resource. Would you mind giving me an example of how I can accomplish this? Thank you!